# Comment s'appelle la phobie des voyages ?

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot, grec

J'ai trouvé sur certaines sources que la phobie des voyages en avions s'appelait l'aerodromophobie.

Y a-t-il un terme pour décrire la peur des voyages quel que soit le moyen de transport ?

Answer (score 10):

Ces mots sont construits sur des racines du grec ancien. Le terme logique serait donc *hodophobie*, du grec ancien [ὁδός](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BD%81%CE%B4%CF%8C%CF%82) signifiant route, voyage. Mais bien que le [Wiktionnaire connaisse](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/hodophobie), on ne peut pas dire que ce soit un terme courant. [Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22hodophobie%22&btnG=Chercher+des+livres&tbm=bks&tbo=1&hl=fr) ne le trouve que dans deux listes de mots. On trouve des termes analogues et aussi peu courants dans d'autres langues : *[hodophobia](http://common-phobias.com/Hodo/index.htm)* en [anglais](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/hodophobia), *Hodophobie* en [allemand](https://books.google.fr/books?id=1GmYx-kmzDIC&pg=PA442&dq="hodophobie"&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=UcahVJCECKOv7AbaxoCIDw&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBA), tous deux attestés dans des dictionnaires de médecine.

Le terme est donc ***hodophobie*** si l'on veut paraître érudit, et ***phobie des voyages*** si l'on veut être sûr d'être compris.

Answer (score 4):

Je n'ai pas trouvé de terme simple pour designer la peur des voyages en tant que tels. Wikipédia a cependant une [liste de phobies](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_phobies) (possiblement non-exhaustive) où j'ai recensé un terme pour pratiquement chaque moyen de transport.

- Aerodromophobie : peur des voyages en avion
- Amaxophobie : peur de la conduite
- Basophobie : peur de marcher
- Cyclophobie : peur de monter sur une bicyclette ou tout autre véhicule à deux roues
- Hippophobie : peur des chevaux, des équidés
- Sidérodromophobie : peur de voyager en train